# What is the difference between single and double quotes in ElasticSearch's query string syntax?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

What is the difference between single and double quotes in ElasticSearch's query string syntax? Just in case I have the terminology wrong, when referencing query string syntax I am referring to the syntax used by kibana's search field on the discover tab.

I have an index with the field `python_type` that is a not analyzed string.

1) `python_type: typeA` finds the expected documents

2) `python_type: "typeA"` also finds the expected documents

3) `python_type: 'typeA'` finds nothing.

Why does the third query string return no results? How does the query string interpret single quotes? On an interesting side note, when the field is analyzed, all three query strings return the expected results.

Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kibana input field doesn't expect JSON data, but what you type in the input field MUST follow the [`query_string` query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax).

As you can see in that documentation, there's no single quote anywhere, i.e. it is not a reserved character of the query syntax.

When querying for `python_type:'typeA'`, the `query_string` query that Kibana sends to ES will look something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "python_type:'typeA'",
          "analyze_wildcard": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is not wrong, but ES will check for documents having a `python_field` containing `'typeA'`, with the single quotes.

Whereas when querying for `python_type:"typeA"` or `python_type:typeA` ES will check for documents having a `python_field` with the exact term `typeA`